# Android Studio/Gradle - Cannot Convert Notation to File or URI

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have found many versions of this on StackOverflow, but none of the answers that I have found have helped and some have even made more errors. But after [forking a project from GitHub](https://github.com/SilenceIM/Silence) and editing the the Gradle and SDK versions, I came across this error:

```
Error:(70, 0) Cannot convert the provided notation to a File or URI: [C:\Android Projects\Personal\VoidMessenger\build\intermediates\proguard-files\proguard-android.txt-2.2.0, C:\Android Projects\Personal\VoidMessenger\proguard.cfg].
The following types/formats are supported:
 - A String or CharSequence path, for example 'src/main/java' or '/usr/include'.
- A String or CharSequence URI, for example 'file:/usr/include'.
- A File instance.
- A URI or URL instance.
```

This came after I imported the project from GitHub into Android Studio, and changing the SDK and build versions to 25 and the Gradle version to 2.2.0. Here is my build.gradle and my settings.gradle.

Build.Gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'witness'
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath files('libs/gradle-witness.jar')
    }
    }

    repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    }

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"

        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25

        try{
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_GIT_COMMIT", "\"" + 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute().text.trim() + "\""
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_GIT_COMMIT", '""'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE'
        exclude 'NOTICE'
        exclude 'asm-license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
            testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles = buildTypes.debug.proguardFiles
            testProguardFiles buildTypes.debug.testProguardFiles
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['test/androidTest/java']
        }
        test {
            java.srcDirs = ['test/unitTest/java']
        }
    }

     lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        }
      }

    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        if (task.name.equals("lint")) {
        task.enabled = false
    }
    }

    def Properties props = new Properties()
    def propFile = new File('signing.properties')

    if (propFile.canRead()){
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

        if (props !=null &&
        props.containsKey('STORE_FILE')     &&
        props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
        props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS')      &&
        props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD'))
        {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
}else {
    println 'signing.properties not found'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
    options.warnings = false
}
dependencies {
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
    compile project (':libs:org.w3c.dom')
    compile 'info.guardianproject.trustedintents:trustedintents:0.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'pl.tajchert:waitingdots:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.1.0'
    compile project (':libs:com.android.support.support-v4-preferencefragment')
    compile ('com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    compile ("com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:1.5.3") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.51.0.0'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'

    compile project (':libs:org.whispersystems.jobmanager')
    compile project (':libs:org.whispersystems.libpastelog:library')
    compile 'org.whispersystems:textsecure-android:1.8.3'
    compile project (':libs:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:library')
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.0.0@aar'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    androidTestCompile ('org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile ('com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest',        module: 'hamcrest-core'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}

dependencyVerification {
    verify = [
            'pl.tajchert:waitingdots:2835d49e0787dbcb606c5a60021ced66578503b1e9fddcd7a5ef0cd5f095ba2c',
            'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:4b5ccba8c4557ef04f99aa0a80f8aa7d50f05f926a709010a54afd5c878d3618',
            'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:b0f530a5b14334d56ce0de85527ffe93ac419bc928e2884287ce1dddfedfb505',
            'com.android.support:design:58be3ca6a73789615f7ece0937d2f683b98b594bb90aa10565fa760fb10b07ee',
            'com.android.support:support-v4:c62f0d025dafa86f423f48df9185b0d89496adbc5f6a9be5a7c394d84cf91423',
            'com.android.support:support-annotations:104f353b53d5dd8d64b2f77eece4b37f6b961de9732eb6b706395e91033ec70a',
            'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:a9b770cffca2c7c5cd83cba4dd12503365de5e8d9c79c479165adf18ab3bc25b',
            'com.doomonafireball.betterpickers:library:132ecd685c95a99e7377c4e27bfadbb2d7ed0bea995944060cd62d4369fdaf3d',
            'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:b8c3fec3a59aac1aa04ccf4dad7179351e54ef7672f53f508151b614c131398a',
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:0ca408c24202a7626ec8b861e99d85eca5e38b73311dd6dd12e3e9deecc3fe94',
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:cbf4604784b4de226262845447a1ad3bb38a6728cebe86562e2c5afada8be2c0',
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:835097bcdd11f5bc8a08378c70d4c8054dfa4b911691cc2752063c75534d198d',
            'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:76ef123957b5fbaebb05fcbe6606dd58c3bc3fcdadb257f99811d0ac9ea9b88b',
            'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:8b5344e206f125e7ba9d684008f36c4992d03853c57e5814125f88496126e3cc',
            'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:e0c1c64575c005601725e7c6a02cebf9e1285e888f756b2a1d73ffa8d725cc74',
            'com.google.zxing:android-integration:89e56aadf1164bd71e57949163c53abf90af368b51669c0d4a47a163335f95c4',
            'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:9625de9d2270e9a280ff4e6d9ef3106573fb4828773fd32c9b7614f4e17d2811',
            'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:c6ef812fba4f74be7dc4a905faa4c2908cba261a94c13d4f96d5e67e4aad4aaa',
            'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1f5a1865796b308c6cdd114acc6e78408b110f0a62fc63553278fbeacd489cd1',
            'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:d71d80e00717a096784482aee21001a9d299fec3833e4ebd87739ed36cf77c54',
            'de.greenrobot:eventbus:61d743a748156a372024d083de763b9e91ac2dcb3f6a1cbc74995c7ddab6e968',
            'info.guardianproject.trustedintents:trustedintents:6221456d8821a8d974c2acf86306900237cf6afaaa94a4c9c44e161350f80f3e',
            'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:15d58d4fac0f7a288d0e5301bbaf501a146f5b3f5921277811bf99bd3b397263',
            'com.nineoldandroids:library:68025a14e3e7673d6ad2f95e4b46d78d7d068343aa99256b686fe59de1b3163a',
            'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:789aca24537022e49f91fc6444078d9de8f1dd99e1bfb090f18491b186967883',
            'com.squareup.okio:okio:5e1098bd3fdee4c3347f5ab815b40ba851e4ab1b348c5e49a5b0362f0ce6e978',
            'javax.inject:javax.inject:91c77044a50c481636c32d916fd89c9118a72195390452c81065080f957de7ff',
            'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:6f56466a9bd0d42934b90bfbfe9977a8b654c058bf44a12bdc2877c4e1f033f1',
            'org.whispersystems:axolotl-android:40d3db5004a84749a73f68d2f0d01b2ae35a73c54df96d8c6c6723b96efb6fc0',
            'org.whispersystems:axolotl-java:6daee739b89d8d7101de6d98f77132fee48495c6ea647d880e77def842f999ea',
            'org.whispersystems:curve25519-android:3c29a4131a69b0d16baaa3d707678deb39602c3a3ffd75805ce7f9db252e5d0d',
            'org.whispersystems:curve25519-java:9ccef8f5aba05d9942336f023c589d6278b4f9135bdc34a7bade1f4e7ad65fa3',
            'org.whispersystems:textsecure-android:aec5fc59952d9f5482491091091687816f46be1144342a0244f48fd55d6ab393',
            'org.whispersystems:textsecure-java:b407ca6d1430204dfabf38e27db22d5177409072a9668238bd1877de7676ad3f',
            'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:a08ca948aa6b220f09d82f16bbbac395f6b78897e9eeac6a9f0b0ba755928eeb',
            'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:89b7f63e2e5b6c410266abc14f50fe52ea8d2d8a57260829e499b1cd9f0e61af',
    ]
```

Settings.Gradle:

```
include 'libs:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:library',
'libs:com.android.support.support-v4-preferencefragment',
'libs:org.w3c.dom',
'libs:org.whispersystems.jobmanager',
'libs:org.whispersystems.libpastelog:library'
```

What could be going on? Also, before editing the gradle version, I got an error saying "Cannot find 'default'". But what could be causing the error stated in this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cannot find default" is related to some missing project module dependencies. This normally happens when you download from net and some modules codes are missing. these have to be added manually.

Comment: Thank you. I found the modules (albeit, after 3 hours of searching) and added them manually.